# How to get the image directory

Tags: image, magento2.2.6, directory

I need to get image directory means **full path**. 
I get the image path from the following code

```
$product = $this->productmodel->load($orderItem->getProductId());
$product->getThumbnail();
```

I got url

```
/w/b/wb02-green-0.jpg
```

I need

```
   /var/www/html/magento/pub/media/catalog/product/w/b/wb02-green-0.jpg
```

How do i get that
i did following code

```
$path = $this->directorylist->getPath("media");
```

it returns

```
/var/www/html/magento/pub/media
```

but i need

```
/var/www/html/magento/pub/media/catalog/product/w/b/wb02-green-0.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, inject below class in your `constructor`

```
     use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config;
     use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;


    /** 
     * @var Config
     */
    private $mediaConfig;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $filesystem;


    /**
     * @param Config $mediaConfig
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     */
    public function __construct(
        Config $mediaConfig,
        Filesystem $filesystem
    )
    {
        $this->mediaConfig = $mediaConfig;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    }
```

Now you can use this like,

```
        $directory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead('media');
        $fullImagePath = $directory->getAbsolutePath($this->mediaConfig->getMediaPath($product->getThumbnail()));
```

Where `$product` is your product object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .  it saves my time . i need one more clarification if $product->getThumbnail() returns null. Then how do i get the default image

Answer (score 4):

A quick solution according to your tests:

```
$fullPath = $this->directorylist->getPath("media").'/catalog/product'.$product->getThumbnail();
```